# Throw error of TypeError:null is not an object (evaluating "$("body").append") while appending html content using jquery which is dynamically injected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, safari-extension

I am developing safari extension and dynamically injecting the jquery and jqueryui as per my requirement . and after successfully injected and loaded i am trying to append html content to it. it throws me this kind of error.

**TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating '$("body").append')**

here is my function which inject the script after page is loaded

```
function injectFiles(files){
    var filesLoaded = 0;
    for(type in files){
      if(type=="css"){
          files[type].forEach(function(v,k){
              var linkTag = document.createElement('link');
              linkTag.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet");
              linkTag.setAttribute("type", "text/css");
              linkTag.setAttribute("href", safari.extension.baseURI +"Scripts/"+v);
              document.body.appendChild(linkTag);
              linkTag.onload = function(){
                  filesLoaded++;
              };
          });
      }else if(type == "js"){
          files[type].forEach(function(v,k){
              var scriptTag = document.createElement('script');
              scriptTag.src = safari.extension.baseURI +"Scripts/"+ v;
              document.body.appendChild(scriptTag);
              scriptTag.onload = function(){
                  filesLoaded++;
              };
          });
      }
    }

    var interval = setInterval(function(){
      if(filesLoaded == files.totalFiles){
          clearInterval(interval);
          showDialog();
      }
    },100);
}
```

function to append html content

```
function showDialog(){
    $("body").append( '<div id="dialog-confirm" title="Question from university tool"><p><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float:left; margin:12px 12px 20px 0;"></span>Is this the right login page for your school?</p></div><div id="dialog-form" title="Please enter your University URL"><input type="text" size=60 name="txtUniversityUrl" id="txtUniversityUrl" value="" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all"></div>');
}
```

Comment: Might suggest that jQuery is not loaded yet. did you try `jQuery("body").append();`? Suggesting that `null` is not an Object would suggest either it does not see a `body` element and thus jQuery is unable to create an Object for that selector.

Comment: When I run it, in FireFox, I see the following error: `files[type].forEach is not a function`

Comment: I have this so far, which should be working as you described, but I can see that `filesLoaded` is not growing beyond `0`. This suggests that the onLoad event is not being triggered when the file links and script sources are being added. https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/nt0c320p/

Comment: Just found this relevant article: http://www.phpied.com/when-is-a-stylesheet-really-loaded/ "Chrome and Safari will not fire events but will update document.styleSheets only when the file arrives, yey!"

Comment: Got `filesLoaded` to update, so it's appending the code now: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/nt0c320p/4/ Still not applying the styles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Created a Working Example that works in FireFox and tested in Safari on Windows. I can test on a Mac later.

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/nt0c320p/7/

**JavaScript**

```
var cssnum = document.styleSheets.length;
var jsnum = document.scripts.length;

function injectFiles(files) {
  var filesLoaded = 0;
  var i = 0;
  for (type in files) {
    if (type == "css") {
      //files[type].forEach(function(v, k) {
      for (i = 0; i < files[type].length; i++) {
        var linkTag = document.createElement('link');
        linkTag.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet");
        linkTag.setAttribute("type", "text/css");
        //linkTag.setAttribute("href", safari.extension.baseURI + "Scripts/" + v);
        linkTag.setAttribute("href", files[type][i]);
        document.head.appendChild(linkTag);
        //linkTag.onload = function() {
        if (cssnum < document.styleSheets.length) {
          filesLoaded++;
        };
        cssnum = document.styleSheets.length;
      }
    } else if (type == "js") {
      //files[type].forEach(function(v, k) {
      for (i = 0; i < files[type].length; i++) {
        var scriptTag = document.createElement('script');
        //scriptTag.src = safari.extension.baseURI + "Scripts/" + v;
        scriptTag.src = files[type][i];
        document.head.appendChild(scriptTag);
        //scriptTag.onload = function() {
        if (jsnum < document.scripts.length) {
          filesLoaded++;
        };
        jsnum = document.scripts.length;
      }
    }
  }

  console.log("Files Loaded: " + filesLoaded);
  var interval = setInterval(function() {
    if (filesLoaded == files.totalFiles) {
      clearInterval(interval);
      showDialog();
    }
  }, 100);
}

function showDialog() {
  var diag1 = $("<div>", {
    id: "dialog-confirm",
    title: "Question from university tool"
  });
  diag1.html('<p><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float:left; margin:12px 12px 20px 0;"></span>Is this the right login page for your school?</p>');
  var diag2 = $("<div>", {
    id: "dialog-form",
    title: "Please enter your University URL"
  });
  diag2.html('<input type="text" size=60 name="txtUniversityUrl" id="txtUniversityUrl" value="" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">');
  $("body").append(diag1).append(diag2);
  diag1.dialog({
    autoOpen: true,
    buttons: [{
      text: "Yes",
      click: function() {
        $(this).dialog("close");
        diag2.dialog("open");
      }
    },
    {
      text: "No",
      click: function() {
        $(this).dialog("close");
      }
    }]
  });
  diag2.dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    width: "75%"
  });

}

var myFiles = {
  "css": [
    "https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"
  ],
  "js": [
    "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js",
    "https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"
  ],
  totalFiles: 3
};

injectFiles(myFiles);
```

Based on my research, Safari does not fire events when new items are loaded, but does update the `document.styleSheets` and `document.scripts` count. So I adjusted the script to look for this activity and update `filesLoaded` when this count grows.

For my testing, I did not have access to your local files, so I called in jQuery and jQuery UI files from CDNs.  I also added a test object, `myFiles`, containing the URLs for those files.

Now that the jQuery files are loaded, we can make use of them to create the Dialog elements. Appending the raw HTML to the body might work out, yet I find it better to build the elements in jQuery, append them, and then initialize `dialog()`. I made some guesses at how you might want them to work.

Let me know if you have questions.

Comment: hi twisty . and thanks for solution and it works. as u says in comment safari cant able to detect the events so i am trying it out another way. just want to confirm is it a correct way. i  get the js and css content through the ajax call and kept it to the style and script tag. even i faces some problem in it. but later i tries this solution it works.